# Heathrow change in terminal flight UK Border control check?

Tags: layovers, lhr, british-airways, jfk

I am traveling from NYC to Mumbai via London. Assume my connecting flight belongs to different terminal.
If I have to change terminal at Heathrow, do I need to go through UK Border control ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no need to pass through immigration control in this circumstance.

Simply follow the purple signs to the new terminal. The inter-terminal bus system is before immigration control.

See also: http://www.heathrowairport.com/heathrow-airport-guide/flight-connections/connection-guides.

If you are flying BA then you are in Terminal 5 for both flights, and there will be no need to use the buses.

Comment: Can you please append a proof ? Would be very helpful !

Comment: There's the Heathrow website: http://www.heathrowairport.com/heathrow-airport-guide/flight-connections/connection-guides. I have travelled through Heathrow hundreds of times, so I know the layout :)

Answer (score -1):

You may need cross the border control. As per https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Below is the excerpt

**Will you pass through UK border control?**

You always pass through border control if you:

- leave the main airport building for any reason
- need to collect your
  bags and check them in to your onward flight

You must also pass through border control if both:

- your onward flight leaves on a different calendar day to when you
  arrive
- there’s nowhere for you to stay overnight in the airport, for
  example in a transit hotel

Check with your airline if you’re not sure if you’ll pass through border control.

Comment: JavaDeveloper's question asked whether changing terminals at Heathrow requires passing through UK border control. S.Bha's answer contains correct information, but is conditional (effectively, "It depends") and doesn't respond to the specific question posed. As shown in the prior answer by Calchas, and supported by a link to Heathrow webpages that address that specific issue, the answer is "no." Thus, downvoted.